# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS/PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT are mutually exclusive

Tags: python, django

I'm upgrading a django code and I faced this error when I runserver, I tryied already to
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
and it doesn't work

Comment: As the error says, you need to specify either `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS`, or `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT`, not both.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to specify either [**`PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout), or [**`PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout-days), not both.

Since the `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` setting was deprecated since [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1) and removed in [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), it might be better to retain the `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` setting, and remove the `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` setting:

```
# settings.py

PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 259200

# no PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS

# …
```

Comment: I'm trying to migrate django 1.8 => 3.2 I don't have settings.py

Comment: @HalimBoussada: then where do you specify the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: in file local.py and then it will be imported to __init__.py

Comment: @HalimBoussada: then likely `local.py` is your settings file.